# Remove Last Window Config

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I have two .py logic file which assosiated with two different .kv template file. In the first logic I set the window config to:

```
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '720')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '360')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'fake')
```

in short, in the last proccess of the first logic file. i destroy the kivy main loop with:

```
Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: App.get_running_app().stop(), 0.1)
```

to go to the next line, which is the next logic file. I trying to make a new setting in the next logic file with:

```
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '920')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '480')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
```

but it seems the windows configuration follow the first config in the first logic file. Is there a way to remove the first configuration?

Comment: Use `Window.size`. Please refer to my post/solution for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution - Using Window.size

Since the only changes are the width and height of the window, an alternative is to use `Window.size`, and you don't have to stop your Kivy App.

Replace

```
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '920')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '480')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
```

with

```
    from kivy.core.window import Window

    Window.size = (920, 480)
```

### Note:

Place it just before invoking the second logic.

[Applying configurations](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.config.html#applying-configurations)

> In order to avoid situations where the config settings do not work or
>   are not applied before window creation (like setting an initial window
>   size), ***Config.set should be used before importing any other Kivy
>   modules. Ideally, this means setting them right at the start of your
>   main.py script.***